# Debian can't wake up after suspend

Tags: linux, debian, kde, systemd, systemctl

After some time my system suspending. After the system has suspended itself I can't wake up the computer.

I use Debian 12 and KDE.

How to fix that?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I've had this issue before using a wireless mouse and keyboard, something to do with power-saving options. Try using a USB mouse/keyboard and see if that fixes the issue.